# Smells like ActiveRecord messes object attributes on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have got a bunch of records in `locations` table:

```
...
*************************** 8. row ***************************
        id: 8
      feed: http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/rss/5day/world/4564.xml
...
*************************** 11. row ***************************
        id: 11
      feed: http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/rss/5day/world/5007.xml
...
```

With the help of this migration:

```
  def self.up
    add_column :locations, :old_feed, :string
    Location.all.each do |l|
      l.old_feed = l.feed
      l.feed.sub!(/^.*?(\d+)\.xml$/, 'http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/\1/Next3DaysRSS.xml') # l.feed = l.feed.sub(...) does not make it any better
      l.save!
    end
  end
```

I want to turn them into

```
...
*************************** 8. row ***************************
        id: 8
      feed: http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/4564/Next3DaysRSS.xml
  old_feed: http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/rss/5day/world/4564.xml
...
*************************** 11. row ***************************
        id: 11
      feed: http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/5007/Next3DaysRSS.xml
  old_feed: http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/rss/5day/world/5007.xml
...
```

What I get instead is

```
...
*************************** 8. row ***************************
        id: 8
      feed: http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/rss/5day/world/4564.xml
  old_feed: http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/4564/Next3DaysRSS.xml
...
*************************** 11. row ***************************
        id: 11
      feed: http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/rss/5day/world/5007.xml
  old_feed: http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/5007/Next3DaysRSS.xml
...
```

Looks like `feed` and `old_feed` somehow got swapped and I can't figure out why.

Rails 2.3.4, MySQL 5.0.

P.S.
I bet it is something stupidly obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: What are the location validations? Any overridden setters/getters?

Comment: P.S. I would not recommend doing data alterations in a migration. You may want to set up a separate rake task for that matter.

Comment: validates_presence_of :name, :feed, :tz
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are modifying the same object (mentioned already).
2. The `feed` attribute is not assigned anything new. You are modifying the return value *in place*.

These combined makes it look like you are reversing the strings. Funny, outcome actually. :-)

Try this instead:

```
def self.up
  add_column :locations, :old_feed, :string
  Location.all.each do |l|
    l.old_feed = l.feed
    # Reassign the new feed and drop the ! from sub!() to return a new string.
    l.feed = l.feed.sub(/^.*?(\d+)\.xml$/,
      'http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/\1/Next3DaysRSS.xml')
    l.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the same object here:

```
l.old_feed = l.feed
l.feed.sub!(/^.*?(\d+)\.xml$/, 'http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/\1/Next3DaysRSS.xml') # l.feed = l.feed.sub(...) does not make it any better
```

it should be instead:

```
l.old_feed = l.feed.clone
l.feed.sub!(/^.*?(\d+)\.xml$/, 'http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/\1/Next3DaysRSS.xml') # l.feed = l.feed.sub(...) does not make it any better
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to explain why feed retains old value.

Comment: Maybe some internals mixed up, but the problem lies there I think.

Comment: You are right. molf answer explains why feed stayed the same.